# ¿Como fijar una imagen de fondo y que esta se recorte horizontalmente (eliminar scroll) según la dimensión de la pantalla?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Me explico, si se tiene una imagen que usa 100% de una pantalla, al hacer zoom, (hablemos del lapso entre la pantalla de tamaño normal del 100% de la pantalla hasta un tamaño de acercamiento de 200%) la imagen comenzara a agrandarse, aparecerán barritas verticales y horizontales para hacer scroll hacia todas direcciones.

Lo que quiero lograr es poder hacer zoom pero que no existan las barritas para hacer scroll horizontalmente (y que la imagen se mantenga en el centro), pero el scroll vertical si debe estar.

Pueden decirme que la imagen se pixelará, pero utilizaré una con formato SVG, por lo que eso no debería pasar. Otra consulta, esto de ir agrandando la imagen y "recortandola" ¿se asocia a algún tipo de concepto?

De antemano gracias.

Comment: Muestra el código con el que armas la vista donde quieres mostrar la imagen de fondo.

Comment: Por favor dime si lo que necesitas es algo [similar a esta pagina](https://www.tenisconnect.mx/) de bienvenida en donde tengo una imagen de fondo al tamaño de la pantalla. Quedo en espera de tus comentarios.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes agregar la imagen como background y luego en un div con el tamaño del viewport, y con css le das un overflow: hidden.

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
.imgdiv {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: url(https://i.ibb.co/tmtR43M/background.jpg) no-repeat center top;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgdiv">
</div>
```

Comment: @hypercarly deberías de hacer una nueva pregunta preguntando eso específicamente para laravel

Comment: @hyper carly, lo que indique te sirve para css, html, no se trabajar en laravel asi que no se si sirva, pero ni tus tags ni el título de la pregunta lo especifican,  en todo caso para cargar la imagen supongo que sabrás como llamarla desde la carpeta donde la alojas en tu proyecto.

Comment: no funciona, si hago zoom la imagen no cambia, solo esta fijada y es inmutable, todo lo contrario a lo que pedí, leíste la pregunta completa?

Comment: Como te dijo @Ruslan López, quisas deberías de formular tu pregunta nuevamente especificando que tu duda es con respecto a laravel, ya que no se exactamente que es lo que estás trabajando, al menos en html y css, en cualquier navegador funciona correctamente. Haz clic en el botón "ejecutar" de la respuesta que te di, luego en "Página completa" realiza zoom y verás que en el navegador si funciona.

Comment: @hypercarly pues suerte y tienes una respuesta, tu pregunta es muy pobre de contenido, debes indicar qué es lo que tienes hasta ahora, para evitar, precisamente, aclaraciones y aclaraciones sobre la misma.

Comment: tanto cuesta entender ue no tiene que ver específicamente con Laravel? si leyeran un poco lo notarían, 2 dedos de frente para ver que solo es html y css